# How can I make one button display the contents of two text boxes on the next screen?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am very new to coding, this being only my 2nd semester in community college and therefore I have a lot to learn.

In my Android Development course, I have been tasked to use the program I've created from the Android Development lesson here - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#java - as the basis for a new program which instead has 2 textboxes and which displays the content the user inputs into those textboxes, onto the display screen, by clicking the 1 send button.

I am stuck.

I've been at this since last Tuesday when the challenge was issued and I've been Google searching, DuckDuckGo searching, searching through stackoverflow, searching through here - https://developer.android.com/docs/ - and I've tried many different approaches but I can't seem to find out how to accomplish this.

!!For the record: I'm not asking someone to code the program/app for me. I'm simply trying to understand *how* to get this 1 button to send 2 textbox contents to the display - I want to learn!!

```xml
//* activity_main.xml */

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ColorActivity"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Number"
        android:hint="edit_name_message"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:layout_below="@+id/Name"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="button_send"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="edit_phone_message"
        android:inputType="phone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Name" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

```java
//* DisplayMessge.java */

package com.example.testapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.testapp.R;

public class DisplayMessage extends Activity {

    private TextView name;
    private TextView number;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_activity);

        name = findViewById(R.id.NameText);
        number = findViewById(R.id.NumberText);

        Intent getText = getIntent();
        String TheName = getText.getStringExtra("Name");
        String TheNumber = getText.getStringExtra("Number");

        name.setText(TheName);
        number.setText(TheNumber);
    }
}
```

```java
//* MainActivity.java */

package com.example.testapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.testapp.DisplayMessage;
import com.example.testapp.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button button;
    private EditText name;
    private EditText number;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initialization of the EditText and the Button
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
        number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayMessage.class);

                String mName = name.getText().toString();
                String mNumber = number.getText().toString();
                //Checking if the Entries are empty
                if (mName != null && mNumber != null) {
                    intent.putExtra("Name", mName);
                    intent.putExtra("Number", mNumber);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text Entries Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

```xml
//* AndroidManifest.xml */

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DisplayMessage">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```xml
//* display_activity.xml */

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/NameText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NumberText"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what you'll want to do is: only have one method to handle the button click. From there, you can put both `EditText`'s in that same method and put them in your intent

Comment: Okay I have entered the most update code above based on the answers I've received. Right now the issue I'm getting is the app stops working and closes when I tap the send button. Also, I believe my onClick in my activity_main.xml file is wrong because it has a red line underneath with an error message saying... corresponding method handler 'public void onCreate (android.view.View) ' not found

Comment: In `DisplayMessageActivity`, your `findViewById`'s don't match your `display_activity.xml` textviews. e.g. shouldn't `findViewById(R.id.Name)` be `findViewById(R.id.NameText)`?

Comment: Okay I finally got it to work using code from Simos Leei's post. I had to create a new project entirely and only have the above classes and not create anything more. Now I'm going to monkey with it to learn how and why it works. Thank you for all your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement the onClick function and send the intent from there.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Button button;
private EditText name;  
private EditText number;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //initialization of the EditText and the Button
     name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);
     number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number);
     button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayMessage.class);

            String mName = name.getText().toString();
            String mNumber = number.getText().toString();
            //Checking if the Entries are empty
            if(mName!=null&&mNumber!=null) {
                intent.putExtra("Name", mName);
                intent.putExtra("Number", mNumber);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Text Entries Missing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

and the Display Class:

```
public class DisplayMessage extends Activity {

 private TextView name;
 private TextView number;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_activity);

    name = findViewById(R.id.NameText);
    number = findViewById(R.id.NumberText);

    Intent getText = getIntent();
    String TheName =getText.getStringExtra("Name");
    String TheNumber =  getText.getStringExtra("Number");

    name.setText(TheName);
    number.setText(TheNumber);

}
```

Also don't forget to add your displayActivity to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <activity android:name=".DisplayMessage">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Now you have to create a second user interface for the DisplayMessageActivity go to res/layout, right click on the layout folder and create a new layout named display_activity. This is my code for the display_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/NameText"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/NumberText"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Lastly this is the activity_main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/ColorActivity"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Number"
    android:hint="edit_name_message"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:layout_below="@+id/Name"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="button_send"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Number" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="edit_phone_message"
    android:inputType="phone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Name" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Greetings, display_activity is the name of the xml file for the display message activity. display_activity contains two text views which ids are "NameText" and "NumberText" as you can see at the code above. I hope i helped! :)

Answer (score -1):

Just reduce your two functions (snedNumber and sendName) to only one function. Inside this function you get the text of both textfields  and put them into your intentextra. then simply start your new activity

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this

```
public void sendInfo(View view) {

Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class); 
EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name); 
String message = name.getText().toString(); 
EditText number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Number); 
String message2 = number.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra("firstString", message); 
intent.putExtra("secondString", message2); 
startActivity(intent); 
}
```

And in your DisplayMessageActivity class onCreate method get it like

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);
    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extra != null){
                String message = extra.getString("firstString");
                String message2 = extra.getString("secondString");
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.